# stopping ODE solver with condition

Tags: r, ode

I would like to terminate ODE solver when the dependent variable exceeded certain value. Consider a simple ODE model

```
library("deSolve")
dModel<- function(t, y, parms) {list(c(y))}
out<-ode(c(1),seq(0,100,1),dModel, parms=NULL)
```

I want to stop solver when `y>100` and display output. I know there is an event of ODE but after reading documentations, I did not understand how to implement in my situation. Could you please provide solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I got an answer to my problem, here is a solution:

```
library("deSolve")
dModel<- function(t, y, parms) {list(c(y))}
rootfun <- function (t, y, parms) { return(y - 100) }
sol<-ode(c(1),seq(0,100,1),dModel, parms=NULL,rootfun = rootfun, method="lsodar")
```

Here is the output:

```
     time      value
1 0.000000   1.000000
2 1.000000   2.718290
3 2.000000   7.389087
4 3.000000  20.085627
5 4.000000  54.598440
6 4.605164 100.000000
```

I can say after `t>4.605164`, `y` would be greater than `100`.